# System.Data.SQLite parseViaFramework

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I was using `System.Data.SQLite` to open some databases on a UNC path. The version in use was 1.0.82 and it worked well. When it was upgraded to 1.0.86 I suddenly started getting an error that it couldn't open the database file.

After a while I discovered that in the `SQLiteConnection` constructor a new parameter was added called `parseViaFramework`. When I set it to true everything started working again.

However there is very little information about what this parameter actually does. I could pick up that it had something to do with how the connection string was parsed, but that's as far as I could get. If I enter `parseViaFramework` into a google search I get only 2 pages of results.

Can anyone tell me exactly what this parameter does?

Answer (score 3):

This addition is to allow the built-in (i.e. framework provided) connection string parser to be used when opening a connection. Apparently, this change is to solve [this](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/b4cc611998) problem.([source](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki))

There's another thing I have noticed myself. When using ExecuteReader, you get an "empty reader", and you need to do the first Read() yourself. I think this is due to the upgrade, as my code was working well without it before. Maybe that's another thing you need to check.

Comment: Yeah I found all of that online already. That's why I asked over here. The issue on the link you posted concerns the use of passwords with whitespace. I am not using a password so it definitely does not contain spaces.

My issue was with UNC paths (and the path I was trying to open contained no spaces either). Without parseViaFramework it failed to open. There is absolutely no mention anywhere about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with UNC and its possible solution with parseViaFramework flag in the constructor of SqliteConnection are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303076/sqlite-cannot-open-network-file-programatically-even-though-worked-before) (first answer) and [there](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/bbdda6eae2)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is mentioned by @ranmoro here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506097/852318

What worked for me was editing the web.config db file connection string by:

> Double the leading two backslashes in the file name
>   (e.g. "\\network\share\file.db").