# SQLite: Cannot open network file programmatically, even though worked before

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, runtime-error

I have used the code below to open a SQLite database file that sits on a network computer for more than a year now almost on a daily basis. Suddenly this morning, I am not able to open the file programmatically.

```
private Boolean Connect(String strPathFile)
{
    // Initialize the connection object.
    this.DbConnection = null;

    try
    {
        // DATABASE: Create the connection string and set the settings.
        String strConnection = @"Data Source=" + strPathFile + @";Version=3;";

        // DATABASE: Connect to the database.
        this.DbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(strConnection);
        this.DbConnection.Open();

        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return false;
}
```

The file is a network resource in the form "\Server\ShareName\FileName.db" (less the double quotes).

Here is the interesting thing. SQLite Administrator has no issues opening up the network database file, none, and repeatedly. I can also open up the file locally. I copied the file to my local drive and simply changed the path inside Visual Studio 2012 (VS2012).

The server seemed fine. It had gone through a reboot at some point since the last time that I checked on it. I presume a Microsoft Update. File Explorer has no issues browsing the folder, and as I said SQLite Administrator can open the network file.

I checked once again on permissions and everyone has full control as well as the server's users have full control, both on the security permissions and on the share permissions. I checked the folder and file, and permissions are the same. I expected as much, because SQLite Administrator can open the file. The server does not have a firewall set up, Windows Firewall or otherwise. I rechecked that this morning as well. Again, SQLite Administrator would have complained about that.

I verified writing, by making a copy of the file on the network drive using File Explorer. That had no issues.

The sever is a Windows Server 2003. I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

I also tried to open up the database in read only mode, but that failed as well. I was expecting that behavior. SQLite Administrator still works nicely.

I tried various other connection strings including SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder() just to see what happens, and all roads lead to Rome, namely:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException occurred
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=unable to open database file
  Source=System.Data.SQLite
  ErrorCode=14
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
       at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
       at SQL.cSQL.Connect(String strPathFile) in C:\<Path to source file>:line 367
  InnerException:
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Same thing occurred to me after upgrading from .net3.5 to .net4. No solution found yet. :(

Comment: I had forgotten about this issue. I did something, sadly do not remember what at the moment, and the problem went away. I did not do anything programmatically to resolve the issue. The resolution was something that I did on the server. You may want to try rebooting the server. The problem had something to do with file locking or the like.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

in version > 1.0.82.0

1. Double the leading two backslashes in the file name
   (e.g. `"\\\\network\share\file.db"`).
2. Use a mapped drive letter.
3. Use the SQLiteConnection constructor that takes the parseViaFramework
   boolean argument and pass 'true' for that argument.

See the SQL post [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/bbdda6eae2)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, however I will not be able to try answer until I go back my job. I got, hopefully just temporarily, laid off. The problem happened on my machine, but worked on other machines, so I do not think that doubling the back slashes would work. I am pretty sure that I did use \\\\network.

Comment: @ranmoro Why is 2. important? I have a problem that when I try to access a database without it (your point 1.) I get the "unable to open database file", but when I try to open the same database using drive letter (the drive is mapped all along, so no changes there) it works fine.

Comment: Thank you, it works! so with the escaping notation in c# you need to write 8 backslashes: \\\\\\\\network\\share\\file.db

Comment: @gajo357 The original (linked) text says: "There are several workarounds to this issue:", point 2 is just one of 3 workarounds. @ rammoro: 4 backslashes works fine for me.

Comment: Figured out, that the DB Browser for SQLite shows the path with slashes (instead of backslash). So i simply replaced backslash (\) with slashes (/) and it worked.

Comment: Adding leading backslashes worked for a few years, but when I updated my project to .NET 4.7.1, SqliteConnection.CreateFile() objected to the 4 leading backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Replacing the UNC (\server\share\folder\file.db) with a mapped drive path (S:\folder\file.db) resolve the issue in my instance.

Comment: What do you do if there is no mapped drive letter? As an example, if folder redirection is used via group policy the path may end up being any old UNC path.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the db file is accessible (e.g. "because SQLite Administrator can open the file"), then option #2 from the answer by ranmoro and GEEF seems to work.  This becomes:

```
bool parseViaFramework = true;
con = new SQLiteConnection( cs, parseViaFramework );
```

in code.  The rationale is discussed in the SQLite check-in comment "mistachkin added on 2013-05-25 21:06:45" in https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/bbdda6eae2

My connection strings are of the form:

```
URI=file:\\SERVER\Data\SqlData\History.db
```

for UNC paths, or

```
URI=file:C:\Data\SqlData\History.db
```

for local paths.

I am using:

```
Visual Studio 2022
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite.Core" Version="1.0.115.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very misleading + irritating. Applications working fine in the local environment get failed to start in client server situation.

It has **mostly** noting to do with the code. Its related to server side.

- Make sure the `Write` access is available for the server folder containing the file.
- UNC [IP based server path] is not supported still, the network path/folder should be mapped to overcome this issue.
- Some sites+users are saying to mention the Version No. in the connection string. All my applications are working fine **without** using it.

Connection String:

```
Data Source=[Mapped Server Location]\[SubFolders]\[FileName].db;
```

Update:

I tried to prepend `\\`  to the UNC path and it worked (added additional `\\` in the beginning only, not in-between).

```
Data Source=\\[UNC]\[SubFolders]\[FileName].db;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for me was to change from backslash to forward slash.

My code environment was PowerShell.

Powershell Examples:

```
# Failed with error: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "unable to open database file"
$db = "Data Source=\\NetworkServer\folder\database.db" 

# Failed with error: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'X' does not exist. - Actually it's exists!!
$db = "Data Source=X:\folder\database.db"

# Failed with error: WARNING: Cannot find the database file
$db = "Data Source=\\\\NetworkServer\folder\database.db"

# Finally Solution! WORKED PERFECT !!!
$db = "Data Source=//NetworkServer/folder/database.db"
connection = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection($db)
connection.Open() ' no exception
```

I spent many hours, tried all the above solutions, but only this worked for me.

Credit: [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303076/sqlite-cannot-open-network-file-programmatically-even-though-worked-before#comment87373851_18506097)