# SQLite database file can't be opened when placed in network folder

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, sqlite-net

Can someone help me to understand why this works fine...

```
Dim cs = "Data Source=C:\folder\Livros.sdb;Version=3;"
Dim cn = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(cs)
cn.Open() ' no exception
```

... while this breaks when opening connection (it is exactly the same file)...

```
Dim cs = "Data Source=\\NetworkServer\folder\Livros.sdb;Version=3;"
Dim cn = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(cs)
cn.Open() ' exception: {"unable to open database file"}
```

... and fix it because I need to place database file in network location so I can access it regardless of the computer I run the application?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think so... I access the same file from SQLite Studio without issues...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so by trial and error I found the solution, although I can't quite understand the reason it works:

```
Dim cs = "Data Source=\\NetworkServer\folder\Livros.sdb;Version=3;"
Dim cn = New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(cs)
cn.ParseViaFramework = True ' JUST ADDED THIS STATEMENT
cn.Open() ' no exception
```

If somebody can explain why `.ParseViaFramework = True` does the trick, please feel free to comment.

Comment: I came across this issue and I wish I knew why this is needed

Answer (score 1):

Similar question was asked here.

[SQLite: Cannot open network file programmatically, even though worked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303076/sqlite-cannot-open-network-file-programmatically-even-though-worked-before)

The top answer gives a few more fixes.  Linking here as this is the first stackoverflow that came up when I searched.  Also I was using a SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder and could not find a way to set the parseViaFramework so the first solution was the one I needed.

1. Double the leading two backslashes in the file name (e.g. "\\\\network\share\file.db").
2. Use a mapped drive letter.
3. Use the SQLiteConnection constructor that takes the parseViaFramework boolean argument and pass 'true' for that argument.