# Unable to open SQLiteConnection on the network directory in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, networking

Using C#, .Net framework 4.8, SQLite 1.0.115

I am using System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection to open a sqllite database on the network drive. But it fails with "unable to open database file". While debugging it I found that it is always pointing to the local drive instead of the network.
example: I have provided "\\NW\test\DB\test.sqlite" as a data source in the connection string. But when I see an exception it says can't find the file in "C:\NW\test\DB\test.sqlite". My program runs on C: drive.

```cs
private SQLiteConnection _connection;
var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "\\\\NW\\test\\DB\\test.sqlite",
                Version = 3,
                ForeignKeys = true,
            };
var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
            

if (_connection == null)
{
    _connection = CreateConnection(connectionString );
    _connection.Open();
}

return _connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
```

On connection open, I am getting this exception

> SQLite error (14): os_win.c:47688: (3) winOpen(C:\NW\test\DB\test.sqlite) - The system cannot find the path specified.

Does anyone know why it is pointing to a local drive instead of the network?

Comment: [Possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506097/880990). `@"data source=\\\\NW\test\DB\test.sqlite;version=3;foreign keys=True"`. Note the @! Also it is `foreign keys`, not `foregn keys`.

Comment: Sorry, there is TYPO in my question. I have added a connection string just for reference here. I will edit my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite: Cannot open network file programmatically, even though worked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303076/sqlite-cannot-open-network-file-programmatically-even-though-worked-before)

Answer (score 0):

By doing multiple trials and errors this change fixed the issue

```
private SQLiteConnection _connection;
var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = @"\\\\NW\\test\\DB\\test.sqlite",
            Version = 3,
            ForeignKeys = true,
        };
var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
        

if (_connection == null)
{
    _connection = CreateConnection(connectionString );
    _connection.Open();
}

return _connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel);
```

So, in the Datasource it needs `"\\\\\\\\NW\\test\\DB\\test.sqlite"` path. Not sure why so many back slashes but this fixed the problem.